# Как привязать url фото профиля?

Tags: java, android, listview, adapter, glide

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Как привязать url фото профиля из `Storage` и юзера чата с этим фото из `Database` в одном адаптере?

После

```
databaseReference=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("chats").child(userid);
                UserProfileImageRef=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("profilepics");

String q = UserProfileImageRef.getDownloadUrl().toString();

Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "url " + q, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Glide.with(MainMenu.this).load(q).into(userImageView);
```

в `userImageView` пусто.

Comment: что приходит в тост, или в логах посмотрите и покажите

Answer (score 2):

Я приведу пример использование на Kotlin. Я думаю вы сможете им воспользоваться.
Как я вижу вы используете Glide и используете Firebase Storage

Для начало посмотрите [Firebase Storage Glide](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/tree/master/storage)

У меня хранятся ссылки на картинки из Storage в String. Поэтому я их конвертирую в 
 `StorageReference`.

```
private fun getStorageReference(imageNames: List<String>?, firebaseStorage: FirebaseStorage): List<StorageReference> {
    val storageImages = arrayListOf<StorageReference>()
    imageNames?.forEach {
        storageImages.add(firebaseStorage.getReference(it))
    }
    return storageImages
}
```

Мой метод загрузки изображения

```
  fun loadImage(context: Context, storageReference: StorageReference, imageView: ImageView) {
        GlideApp.with(context)
                .load(storageReference)
                .placeholder(getCircularProgressDrawable(context))
                .error(getErrorDrawable())
                .into(imageView)
    }
```

Пример его вызова `ImageUtils.loadImage(context, it, view.fileImage)`

Так же обязательно нужен `class` :

```
@GlideModule
class MyAppGlideModule : AppGlideModule() {

    override fun registerComponents(context: Context, glide: Glide, registry: Registry) {
        registry.append(StorageReference::class.java, InputStream::class.java,
                FirebaseImageLoader.Factory())
    }
}
```

Надеюсь это вам поможет))